# Counting consecutive alphabets and hyphens and encode them as run length

Tags: python, python-2.7, collections, counter

How do I encode my hyphenated fasta format string to group all consecutive Nucleotide and hyphens and [encode them as run length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

Consider my sequence as "ATGC----CGCTA-----G---". The string has sequence of [Nucleotide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleotide) followed by sequence of hyphens. I am trying to group all consecutive Nucleotide as the letter `M` and consecutive hyphens as letter `D` and prefix it with the size of the sub sequence.

The final result out of this encoding should be `4M4D5M5D1M3D`.

The following pictorial graphic explains it further

```
ATGC----CGCTA-----G---
 |   |    |    |  |  |
 V   V    V    V  V  V
4M   4D  5M    5D 1M 3D
```

When I use `Counter` or `list.count()`, I get `"M":10 "D":12`:

```
from collections import Counter

seq="ATGC----CGCTA-----G---"

M=0
D=0   

cigar=[]

for char in seq:    
    if char.isalpha():
        M+=1
        cigar.append("M")   
    else:
        D+=1
        cigar.append("D")

print Counter(cigar)
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Question is: I am trying to achieve something like 4M4D5M5D1M3D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem is ideal for [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

**Implementation**

```
from itertools import groupby
''.join('{}{}'.format(len(list(g)), 'DM'[k]) 
        for k, g in groupby(seq, key = str.isalpha))
```

**Output**
    '4M4D5M5D1M3D'

**Explanation**

Notably, the key function is crucial here. Group the sequence based on it being an alphabet or not. Once done, it should be straight forward to count the size of each group and figure out the type of the group from the key element.

**Some explanation of code**

- `'DM'[k]`: This is just a nifty way of representing `"M" if k == True else "D"`
- `len(list(g))`: Determines the size of each group. Alternatively, it could have been written as `sum(1 for e in g)`
- `'{}{}'.format`: String formatting to create a concatenation of the consecutive frequency and the type
- `''.join(`: To join the list elements as a string sequence.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM.: Where is your solution or am I missing something ?

Comment: Great and elegant solution! Maybe the question could be edited to better reflect the actual problem?

Comment: I wouldn't do it so tersely, do use `"M" if k else "D"`. You read code more often than you write it!

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
seq='ATGC----CGCTA-----G---'

output = ''
for section in re.split('(-*)', seq):
    if section.isalpha():
        output += str(len(section)) + 'M'
    elif section !='':
        output += str(len(section)) + 'D'
print output
```

Answer (score 3):

classical approach :

```
seq="ATGC----CGCTA-----G---"

def MD(c):
    if c.isalpha():return "M"
    else : return "D"

count=1
string=""
for i in range(len(seq)-1):
    if MD(seq[i])==MD(seq[i+1]): count+=1
    else: 
        string=string+str(count)+MD(seq[i])
        count=1
string=string+str(count)+MD(seq[-1])
print string
```